# Convert existing SVN repo to git-svn

Tags: git, svn

I have an existing SVN repo. The remote is SVN too. I would like to use git-svn to manage it locally.

How can I do that without having to check out all the files again?

Answer (score 0):

**The recommended link** to begin with 
https://help.github.com/articles/importing-from-subversion

**Some previous stackoverflow discussions**

[Convert an SVN checkout to use git (git-svn)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/826865/convert-an-svn-checkout-to-use-git-git-svn)

[How to migrate SVN repository with history to a new Git repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79165/how-to-migrate-svn-with-history-to-a-new-git-repository)

**Other links for reference**

http://john.albin.net/git/convert-subversion-to-git

http://www.mabishu.com/blog/2011/01/13/migrate-subversion-repository-to-git-without-loosing-data/